# SP.UI.Status anonymously inaccessible

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, client-object-model, office-365, sp.ui

Using Office 365 (SharePoint Online) I have stumbled into an annoying thing. Some parts of the JavaScript CSOM does not seem to be accessible when your browse the site anonymously. If  Firstly I tried to add a list item to a list, I got a *500 (Internal Server Error)* response from *Client.svc*.

And now I'm trying to use the status message (SP.UI.Status) but it is *undefined*. I've tried some of the [SOD methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff408081%28v=office.14%29.aspx), like [excuteFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx), without any luck.

Remind that all above works perfectly when logged and thus not being anonymously.

And I really don't know how to troubleshoot this issue.

How do I get the SP.UI.Status anonymously available and working?

Comment: Do you have a Ribbon when anonymous, or have you hidden it for anon users?

Comment: It's hidden, probably by "default". I'm using the Starter Master Page by Randy Drisgill, http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Try showing it in anonymous to see if it works (what a user can do is restricted) - most of SP.UI is loaded via the ribbon stuff.

Comment: If it does work, then you can manually pull in the .js files that the ribbon loads to get your functionality back.

Comment: I figured it out without implicating the ribbon. Anyhow, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried some more and got it working, I must have used the **executeFunc** falsely.
Using the executeFunc as below makes SP.UI.Status available.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.UI.Status', statusLoaded); // Worked!
```

To me its a bit strange probably because of the naming conventions which are confusing.
My intuitive try was something like this;

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.js', 'SP.UI.Status', statusLoaded); // Did not work
```